# Shell redirection operation >|?

Tags: io-redirection

What is the difference between these two redirections?

```
[localhost ~]$ echo "something" > a_file.txt
[localhost ~]$ echo "something" >| a_file.txt
```

I can't seem to find any documentation about >| in the [help](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`>|` overrides the `noclobber` option in the shell (set with `$ set -o noclobber`, indicates that files can not be written over).

Basically, with `noclobber`, you get an error if you try to overwrite an existing file using `>`:

```
$ ./program > existing_file.txt
bash: existing_file.txt: cannot overwrite existing file
$
```

Using `>|` will override that error and force the file to be written over:

```
$ ./program >| existing_file.txt
$
```

It's analogous to using the `-f` or `--force` option on many shell commands.

From the [Bash Reference Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Redirections) Section "3.6.2 Redirecting Output":

> If the redirection operator is `>`, and the `noclobber` option to the set builtin has been enabled, the redirection will fail if the file whose name results from the expansion of word exists and is a regular file. If the redirection operator is `>|`, or the redirection operator is `>` and the `noclobber` option is not enabled, the redirection is attempted even if the file named by word exists.

Searching for "bash noclobber" generally brings up articles that mention this somewhere. See [this question on SuperUser](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/45201/bash-what-does-do), [this section in O'Reilly's "Unix Power Tools"](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix/upt/ch13_06.htm), and [this Wikipedia article on Clobbering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clobbering) for examples.